# With sed, how to add a text between 2 patterns when another pattern is not found inside them?

Tags: sed

With sed, how can I add a text (here `Inserted_text` for the example) between 2 patterns (here `Pattern_one` and `Pattern_two`) when another pattern (here `Pattern_of_interest`) is not found inside them ?

In my file, the `end of line` character is just a `\n` (i.e. Unix format), but I work under msdos with GNU sed version 4.0.7.

The command I tried but didn't work:

```
sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;/\nPattern_one/ /\nPattern_of_interest/! /\nPattern_two/ a/Inserted_text/" file.txt
```

The patterns are all three starting at the beginning of a line.

The "blabla" in the example below can be anything.

Example of input file:-

```
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Pattern_of_interest blabla
blabla
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
blabla
blabla
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
```

Desired output file (with insertion at top, iow, beside Pattern_one):

```
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Pattern_of_interest blabla
blabla
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Inserted_text
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Inserted_text
blabla
blabla
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
```

Desired output file (with insertion at bottom, iow, beside Pattern_two):

```
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Pattern_of_interest blabla
blabla
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
Inserted_text
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
blabla
Pattern_one
blabla
blabla
Inserted_text
Pattern_two
blabla
blabla
```

I need to insert at top, but if you could also tell me how to insert at bottom, it would be nice too.

Comment: I think this is better suited for `awk`, do you have that command?

Comment: @Sundeep I often use *block* and *under-block* research and treatment by using [tag:sed]! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45345452/1765658)

Comment: @F.Hauri and that only reinforces my opinion that `awk` is better suited... that code is greek to me, I've tried to understand it in the past but couldn't.. and using perl/awk with more commonly used programming flow is easier for me (and imo for majority of others as well)

Comment: @Sundeep : I agree with you about the fact that awk script is simpler to handle. Usually, I rely on sed for preformatting from scratch data extract stored in plain text and then process the file with awk when field and record separators have been inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There it is:

```
sed -e '
    /Pattern_one/,/Pattern_two/{
      //{
         /one/h;
         /two/{
            H;
            x;
            /Pattern_of_interest/!s/\n/\nInserted_text\n/;
            p;
         };
         d;
      };
    //!H;
    d;
}' -i file.txt
```

And there is the difference between `oldfile.txt` and `file.txt`:

```
diff -W 60  -y oldfile.txt file.txt
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_one                       Pattern_one
Pattern_of_interest blabla        Pattern_of_interest blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_two                       Pattern_two
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_one                       Pattern_one
                             >    Inserted_text
Pattern_two                       Pattern_two
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_one                       Pattern_one
                             >    Inserted_text
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_two                       Pattern_two
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
```

#### And if you prefer having your *Pattern of interest* just before *Pattern two*:

```
sed -e '                 
    /Pattern_one/,/Pattern_two/{
      //{
         /one/h;
         /two/{
            H;
            x;
            /Pattern_of_interest/!s/\nPattern_two/\nInserted_text&/;
            p;
         };
         d;
      };
    //!H;
    d;
}' -i file.txt
```

... Then diff become:

```
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_one                       Pattern_one
Pattern_of_interest blabla        Pattern_of_interest blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_two                       Pattern_two
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_one                       Pattern_one
                             >    Inserted_text
Pattern_two                       Pattern_two
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
Pattern_one                       Pattern_one
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
                             >    Inserted_text
Pattern_two                       Pattern_two
blabla                            blabla
blabla                            blabla
```

#### Another aproach, without having to store whole block in memory

But this way implie to add *Inserted text* at end of block:

```
sed -e '                 
    /Pattern_one/,/Pattern_two/{
      //{
         /one/h;
         /two/{
            x;
            /Pattern_of_interest/!iInserted_text
            x;
         };
      };
      /Pattern_of_interest/h;
}' -i file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed '/Pattern_one/{:a;N;/Pattern_two/!ba;/Pattern_of_interest/! {/Pattern_one/s/\n/&Inserted_text\n/};P;D;}' file
```

Lines between `Pattern_one` and `Pattern_two` are added to the pattern space and if `Pattern_of_interest` is not found in the block, insert new text after `Pattern_one`.

To insert text before `Pattern_two`:

```
sed '/Pattern_one/{:a;N;/Pattern_two/!ba;/Pattern_of_interest/! {/Pattern_two/s/.*\n/&Inserted_text\n/};P;D;}' file
```

Comment: This way, you could not choose to place *Inserted text* at 1st line of block.  If you won't store whole block in memory, I'v added another way of doing this, by using block anyway.

Comment: @F.Hauri I edited. First command to insert new text after `Pattern_one`, second to insert  before `Pattern_two`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Pattern_one/!b;:a;N;/Pattern_two/!ba;/Pattern_of_interest/b;h;s/\n.*//p;x;s/^[^\n]*\n//;iInserted text' file
```

Find the address with `Pattern_one` otherwise print as normal (no further processing).

Introduce a location `:a` and append the next line to the pattern space (PS) using the `N` command.

Check if the PS contains the address `Pattern_two` and if not loop back to location `:a` and repeat.

The PS now contains all the lines from `Pattern_one` to `Pattern_two`.

Check the PS to see if it contains the `Pattern_of_interest` and if it does break out `b` and print as normal doing no further processing in this cycle.

If it does not, copy the PS into the hold space (HS) using the `h` command and then using the substitution command `s/\n.*//p`, print the first line of the PS.

Swap the HS for the PS using the command `x` and prep the PS to contain the remaining lines minus the first one using another substitution command `s/^[^\n]*\n//`.

Now insert new text using the `i` command.

The sed cycle will then print what remains in the PS after the insertion command has been executed.

For inserting text before `Pattern_two`:

```
sed '/Pattern_one/!b;:a;N;/Pattern_two/!ba;/Pattern_of_interest/b;h;s/\n[^\n]*$//p;x;s/^.*\n//;iInserted text' file
```

This uses essentially the same code except the two substitution commands at the end first print all the lines bar the last in PS and then prep the PS to contain only the last line after the insertion command has been executed.